# MySQL fails because of FK constraint that should not exist

Tags: mysql

I'm running the following very boring query:

```
alter table mytable change user_id user_id varchar(36) null default null,
add foreign key (user_id) references users(id) on delete set null;
```

But it fails with the following error:

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
(`mydatabase`.`#sql-602_60f`, CONSTRAINT `#sql-602_60f_ibfk_4`
FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL
```

The problem is that that foreign key constraint doesn't exist, so I can't delete it. There are 3 foreign key constaints on the table (mytable_ibfk_1, mytable_ibfk_2, mytable_ibfk_3), but nothing with the name mentioned, and trying to delete it produces another error.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: It looks like the issue isn't that the FK exists and must be deleted, it's that your attempt to add it interferes with existing rows in the database that can't meet the new FK's constraints.

Comment: There may be values in `user_id` which do not exist in the referenced column `users.id`.

Comment: Oh right, I understand now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As Michael Berkowski pointed out, I was misreading the error, which was pointing to conflicting values in the two columns, not to an existing phantom constraint that I couldn't delete.

The root of the problem was that the column had previously accepted empty string values (''), and those needed to be converted to NULL in order for the foreign key constraint to be put in place.